# Access to the path '\\Core-01\Media\Temp' is denied - aspnet user needed

Tags: networking, iis, asp.net

Windows 2016 | IIS10 | IIS Server Farm

For starters.
I just now moved all sites from the backup server to the Web Forest.
And the one site I am having the titled issue with luckily is not a part of the site where people can see it—just me.

I had run into this issue before a few months ago and was able to resolve it without to much fuss.
However, there seems to be an issue now.

> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and
>   the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.

Users added to [Security] tab permissions

> IUSR NETWORK SERVICE pool@domain.local
>   (Custom pool identity)
>   Administrators (Default)

(ASPNET User is NOT available, and I have no idea on how to enable this user)

> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File Explorer,
>   choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. 
>   Click "Add"
>   to add the appropriate user or group. 
>   Highlight the ASP.NET account,
>   and check the boxes for the desired access.

The issue now is, I DO NOT have the ASPNET user as an option to chose from, and this used to be an option a few months back.
So, what happened to it?

UPDATE
I followed the instructions on this site here.
[ASPNET User Identity Model](http://rdpsupport.resortdata.com/Customers/Knowledge/KB-IRMNET/IRMNetInstall/IdentityASPNET.htm)
I could not get the **aspnet_regiis -I** to work with any other version of asp.net on the server.
So, I had to use the one which is used on the page.
After installing asp.net 3.0 (Which comes with 2.0)
And then running the **aspnet_regiis -I** 
I rebooted the server.
Still, the ASPNET user does not show.

So, I am at a loss, people.
It used to be here, as I was using the user before in the 2016 server.
So, what happened to it?
Clearly, it is needed for this site, since the **Network Service** does not do it.

Any ideas on this would be great.
Wayne

Comment: You got that ASPNET user error message, simply because your app runs on the legacy .NET Framework shipped more than a decade ago. The ASPNET user is obsolete, and that's why you cannot get it back no matter how. Instead, focus on the application pool identity currently configured for that web app please. Use a service account from AD, and then grant that account permissions on the remote file share.

Comment: Hello, Lex Li. I have the application pool custom domain user set with permissions to access the directory. Is there a certain "Member Of Group" that I need to add to the App pool user, in order for it to gain access?  I will list all groups to the topic.

Comment: Lex Li. Your comment made me look into my IIS, and at each server in the forest. It seems the "Shared Config" is not populating correctly, or, not at all on some of the servers. So, I had to add the Custom App Pool user to each of the IIS instances, and then it worked. If you would like to add in your comment as an answer, I will accept it. And thank you. Sometimes it takes someone else to help you see something you might not have otherwise noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked a very good question with exact error messages, so it is clear what issue you met. So we go through the whole process.

An ASP.NET application (likely .NET 2.x/3.x) gave you an error message

> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and
>   the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be the anonymous user (typically
>   IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.

which should be very clear if the web app runs on IIS 5.x/6.0/7.0. However, time flies so people can be surprised to see that accounts like IUSR_MACHINENAME or {MACHINE}\ASPNET are gone, and Network Service is not the base process identity any more (IIS 7.5+).

Thus, the only correct hint is "the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5", which like I commented above is the custom domain account you used for this web application.

To summarize the issue again, ASP.NET web app running under a custom domain account cannot access a remote file share, and reports an error.

With this in mind, the rest is rather simple for you, to locate whether the right permissions are set. Even though on your servers actually another problem (failed shared configuration) prevents the things from working, you can easily resolve it.

So, keep up the good work on your side to always focus on the exact symptoms and ask the right questions.

Comment: Thank you once again. Got this issue taken care of, and now on to fix the next issue. And this next one, I had not seen in previous builds.